# How to connect to server as root in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, ssh

I want to know how I can access the following as root:
Places>Connect to server

This is to connect to a server that needs a public key that I only have as root

Thanks

Comment: executing sudo nautilus lets me browse local files as root.  not sure if it works in the case you're referring to

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, go to `Places -> Connect to Server -> Select`:

- **Service type:** select SSH
- **Server:** Type in your servers ip address here, such as 123.456.789.123
- **Port:** Leave blank
- **Folder:** Leave blank
- **User Name:** root

Press `connect`

Now you should get prompted for a password for your RSA/DSA keys. Key in your password and voila! It connects!

Comment: Have you tried it? As far as I know, on Debian Ubuntu you cannot connect via ssh as root.

Comment: Yes I use it every day.

Comment: @natema: you might have set `PermitRootLogin` to `no` in your server sshd config file. Check this out

Comment: connecting as root seems a little risky, and not really a good practice. Is there no way to get a password prompt when you want to open as particular file as root?